# How to properly use the `block` function

Tags: maxima

I'm attempting to write a little function where it takes 2 vectors, changes the sign on the first entry of the first vector and then perform the dot product on them. However, when I do this, the global value of the changed vector in the function is changed outside the function.

I've attempted to use the `block` function to protect the global values of the vectors, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

```
a: matrix([3],[4],[5]);
b: matrix([4],[5],[6]);
f(x,y):=block([x:x,y:y],x[1]:-x[1],x.y);
f(a,b);
```

I expect the answer to be 38, which it is on the first time I run `f(a,b);` but when I do it a second time, I get 62 because `a` has changed globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a matrix to the function, and this matrix is not copied, it's a reference to the same matrix. As Maxima documentation says,

> Matrices are handled with speed and memory-efficiency in mind. This means that assigning a matrix to a variable will create a reference to, not a copy of the matrix. If the matrix is modified all references to the matrix point to the modified object (See copymatrix for a way of avoiding this)

So you need to copy a matrix to handle it independently:

```
f(x,y):=block([x:x, y:y, m:m, n:n],
    m:copymatrix(x), 
    n:copymatrix(y),
    m[1]:-m[1],
    m.n);
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks for that insight about passing matrices to functions.